# convert tuples in a list to string

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a list as:

```
data = [
  (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5),
]
```

How do I combine the tuples as strings one by one:
    For example

```
(1,2) = "12"
(1,3) = "13"
```

Comment: by the way.. 'list' is primitive kind of type in Python. So it is usually recommend to NOT to use 'list' as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> lst = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
>>> [str(x) + str(y) for x, y in lst]
['12', '13', '14', '15', '23', '24', '25', '34', '35', '45']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
new_list = ["".join(map(str, item)) for item in list]
```

This creates a new list from the old list where each item is concatenated (after string-conversion).

This works for tuples having any number of values.

Example: https://repl.it/repls/JubilantVacantWoodstorks

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? I wrote this answer at the same time as the upvoted one and my answer is also correct and is not a duplicate of the other one? Also I am the only one who provided an runnable example

Comment: It wasn't me, but my guess is because this answer looks more complicated, but the advantage of this answer is that it can handle tuples of any length

Comment: Also FYI I just realised I got a downvote on my answer too for no reason, so my comment above is probably wrong. Actually every single answer here has a downvote

Answer (score -1):

```
temp_list = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)]
new_list = map(lambda obj: str(obj[0])+str(obj[1]), temp_list)
```

Comment: `map`+`lambda` should usually be a list comprehension—especially if you have to apply `list` to it (in Python 3).

Comment: I agree with you @DavisHerring

Answer (score -1):

another less efficient way you can go about is to loop through the entire list, then grab the first and second elements of each tuple, concatenate them, then return them in a list.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

`res_list = map(lambda (x,y): str(x) + str(y), list)`

map is higher order function which takes a function and a list and applies a function to every element of list. In above case str(x) + str(y) a '+' string concatenation operator working two string operands and returns a final string. Hence resultant list will be list of string. which is expected output.

result:

`['12', '13', '14', '15', '23', '24', '25', '34', '35', '45']`

Comment: Please describe your answer

Comment: map is higher order function which takes a function and a list and applies a function to every element of list. In above case str(x) + str(y) a '+' string concatenation operator working two string operands and returns a final string. Hence resultant list will be list of string. which is expected output. `['12', '13', '14', '15', '23', '24', '25', '34', '35', '45']`

Comment: Perfect, please edit the answer with adding the comment text.

Comment: Done. Edited the above answer.